# Delete statefulset pods to update configmap - without deleting PVs?

Tags: kubernetes

In K8s, if I have a statefulset deployed with three replicas, how do I update a configmap without losing the data on the associated persistent volumes? There are some odd constraints on this including that -

1. The nodes all need to have the same config (it relates to TLS and needs to be pushed to all three before they can talk to one another).
2. There need to be three replicas for the application to reach a quorum and report itself as online via the standard probes.
3. I don't mind a few minutes downtime while this happens.

A simple `rollout restart` fails because the updated configmap makes one node incompatible with the others. This prevents the rollout from continuing because all need to be restarted synchronously.

Forcing a restart by deleting the pods works in terms of refreshing the config synchronously but appears to delete the persistent volumes (this also seems odd, is this standard behaviour, or something my application is doing behind my back?)

Appreciate some advice here - how do the pros do it? I feel like I must be misconceptualising the problem somehow here.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be switching `delete-claim` the flag (when using the `persistent-claim`). This change effects how the cluster controller behaves when ConfigMap deletion happens and if it has to delete or not PVCs. While updating ConfigMap just set  `delete-claim` = false in PVC definition.

Take a look: [configmap-update](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/issues/152).

Comment: Hmmm, so because the current solution is using a statefulset, there are no manually managed PVCs involved... The PVCs are automatically created by the statefuset. Also, we aren't deleting the ConfigMap, we're deleting the pods in the statefulset so that the application picks up the new ConfigMap (which is loaded at startup only.)

Comment: Remember that  PVCs have a lifetime independent of pods. If you have PVC defined in StatefulSet and want PV still exists try to set ReclaimPolicy to Retain in this case it won't be deleted even if PVC is gone. ReclaimPolicy is set as Delete by default.